# Android compose ktor failed with error Lio/ktor/utils/io/NativeUtilsJvmKt

Tags: android, retrofit, android-jetpack-compose, ktor

i am trying to setup ktor replacing retrofit on a compose simple android app but i am getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio/ktor/utils/io/NativeUtilsJvmKt;
at io.ktor.client.features.HttpSend.<init>(HttpSend.kt:49)
at io.ktor.client.features.HttpSend.<init>(HttpSend.kt:41)
at io.ktor.client.features.HttpSend$Feature.prepare(HttpSend.kt:75)
at io.ktor.client.features.HttpSend$Feature.prepare(HttpSend.kt:72)
at io.ktor.client.HttpClientConfig$install$3.invoke(HttpClientConfig.kt:77)
at io.ktor.client.HttpClientConfig$install$3.invoke(HttpClientConfig.kt:74)
at io.ktor.client.HttpClientConfig.install(HttpClientConfig.kt:97)
at io.ktor.client.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.kt:172)
at io.ktor.client.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.kt:81)
at io.ktor.client.HttpClientKt.HttpClient(HttpClient.kt:43)
```

My service is like this:

```
 interface ApiService {

  suspend fun getProducts(): List<ResponseModel>

  companion object {

    private val json = kotlinx.serialization.json.Json {
      ignoreUnknownKeys = true
      isLenient = true
      encodeDefaults = false
    }

    fun create(): ApiService {
      return ApiServiceImpl(
        client = HttpClient(Android) {
          // Logging
          install(Logging) {
            level = LogLevel.BODY
          }
          // JSON
          install(JsonFeature) {
            serializer = KotlinxSerializer(json)
            //or serializer = KotlinxSerializer()
          }
          // Timeout
          install(HttpTimeout) {
            requestTimeoutMillis = 15000L
            connectTimeoutMillis = 15000L
            socketTimeoutMillis = 15000L
          }
        }
      )
    }
  }
}
```

and ApiServiceImpl

```
class ApiServiceImpl(private val client: HttpClient) : ApiService {

  override suspend fun getProducts(): List<ResponseModel> {
    return client.get {
      url(HttpRoutes.PRODUCTS)
    }
  }
}
```

On my main activity I just want to make the api call and just display an attribute of the first item of the list(just for verifying that the call was successful).

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

  private val service = ColorBarApiService.create()

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
      MaterialTheme {
        // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
        Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
          val products = produceState(
            initialValue = emptyList<ResponseModel>(),
            producer = {
              value = service.getProducts()
            }
          )
          // just to see if api call is success
          Text(text = "First product has description ${products.value[0].description}!")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Finally on app `build.gradle` I am using these:

```
  // ktor
  implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version"
  // HTTP engine: The HTTP client used to perform network requests.
  implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktor_version"
  // The serialization engine used to convert objects to and from JSON.
  implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktor_version"
  // Logging
  implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktor_version"

  implementation "io.ktor:ktor-utils-jvm:$ktor_version"

  implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:$ktor_version"


  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:$serialization_version"
```

with values

```
    ext {
    compose_ui_version = '1.2.1'
    koin_version= "3.2.2"
    koin_android_version= "3.2.3"
    koin_android_compose_version= "3.2.2"
    koin_ktor= "3.2.2"
    ktor_version = '1.6.4'
    serialization_version = '1.4.1'
  }
```

Comment: Could you please try to use the latest version of Ktor 2.1.2?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman Thanks a lot!! I used the latest version just like you said and it works as expected. Of course I had to make some changes in order to migrate from 1.6.X to 2.X.X. For more details about migration here (https://ktor.io/docs/migrating-2.html#server-package)